# Zend xmlrpc error

Tags: php, zend-framework, xml-rpc

I have this error with Zend (v1) XmlRpc client :

Uncaught exception 'Zend_XmlRpc_Client_FaultException' with message 'Failed to parse response'.

It's the error status 651.

The call never reaches the class/method requested, it seems that the call is not fired like it was blocked or something. I'm in debug on the method called and it's not triggered.

PHP version is 5.4.

**EDIT**

Here is the code :

Caller class :

```
require_once 'library/Zend/XmlRpc/Client.php';

class FrontService
{
    private $client;

    public function __construct($xmlRpc)
    {
       $this->client = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client($xmlRpc);

    }

    public function call($name, $params = array())
    {

        return $this->client->call($name, $params);
    }
}
```

Call to the class :

```
$this->_fs = new FrontService(HM_Config::getParam("amf-url"));
$editos = $this->_fs->call('getEdito',$params_home);
```

Code called :

```
include_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__) .'/..') 
.'/application/bootstrap.php';
require_once '_config.php';
require_once 'DirectDbConnectionV2.php';

class FrontGateway extends DirectDbConnectionV2
{
    public static $smStatic;

    function __construct()
    {
        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

        $this->sm  = self::$smStatic;   
        $this->log = new Log();
        $this->log->set_file('amfDbConnection');
        $this->log->write('construct bordel');
    }
}
FrontGateway::$smStatic = $sm;
$controllerManager = $sm->get('EditoWebsiteMVC\ControllerManager');
$controllerManager->run('EditoWebsite\Controller\UIGateway', 'xmlRpc');
```

Code that should be executed :

```
namespace EditoWebsite\Controller;

use EditoWebsiteMVC\AbstractController;
use EditoWebsiteMVC\ViewRender\CLI as CLIViewRender;
use EditoWebsiteMVC\ViewRender\HTMLTemplate as HTMLTemplateViewRender;
use Zend_XmlRpc_Server as XmlRpcServer;

class UIGatewayController extends AbstractController
{
    public function xmlRpcAction()
    {
        $svr = new XmlRpcServer();
        $svr->setClass('FrontGateway');
        echo $svr->handle();
        exit;
    }
}
```

The code in the *getEdito* method from the *DirectDbConnectionV2* is never reached.

Is there something I need to enable on the server ? or a port that I need to open ?

**EDIT EDIT**

I should mention that the code is working on another server that I've access to, is there anything I should compare / check to maybe solve that issue ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's enough info to even make a guess, but let me try.

I've faced similar issue, where requests sent never reached the server. It turned out to be that `Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket` adapter is binding to an IPv6 and due to routing issues request never got to the server.

In the end, what solved the issue was:

```
$client->getAdapter()->setStreamContext(array(
    'socket' => array('bindto' => '0:0'),
));
```

where `$client` is an instance of `Zend_Http_Client`.

Again, it's just a shot in the dark, but could be worth trying. :)

**Edit:**

In your case, you should add following to `FrontService` constructor:

```
$this->client->getHttpClient()->getAdapter()->setStreamContext(array(
    'socket' => array('bindto' => '0:0'),
));
```

**Edit Edit:**

Since back on 1.9.0 there's no `getAdapter` on Zend_Http_Client, you have to create adapter yourself and pass it to http client:

```
public function __construct($xmlRpc)
{
   $this->client = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client($xmlRpc);

   $adapter = Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket();
   $adapter->setStreamContext(array(
       'socket' => array('bindto' => '0:0'),
   ));

   $this->client->getHttpClient()->setAdapter($adapter);
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: I've edited my question to make it more complete, could you please tell me where to add that code ? I tried but didn't find out.

Comment: Edited my answer. :)

Comment: got that error Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend_Http_Client::getAdapter() but I have a library/Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Socket.php that has a setStream context method.

Comment: Can you check if your `library/Zend/Http/Client.php` has `getAdapter` method? It should be around line 950.

Comment: No it's not there :-/.

Comment: Which version are you using? I'm looking at `1.12.16` atm.

Comment: Mine is 1.9.0. :-(

Comment: GitHub repo doesn't go that far, had to download it. Let me edit my answer, since it's not going to be that short. :)

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and time but I still got the same error message : PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_XmlRpc_Client_FaultException' with message 'Failed to parse response'

Comment: Ah bollocks... :) Well, at least we tried. I hope you get to the bottom of this soon.